# How can I make a keyboard image like this one?

Tags: text, images, software-recommendation, 3d

I have seen a lot of images like these on different web sites:
[image: keyboard1]
[image: keyboard2]
How can I make one?

Answer (score 2):

This is an easy receipe for Adobe Illustrator
[image]